# Quickify splitting of Data into rows via Numpy: Pieces of Data based on the row index

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, slice, numpy-slicing

I'm working with wav files at the moment and want to split up the data array with all channels into a matrix, where every row is the specific channel data.
I have the data array like so, and wish the following matrix format:

```
data = [channel1_frame1, channel2_frame1, ..., channeln_frame1, channel1_frame2, ...] # integers
matrix = [[channel1_frame1, channel1_frame2, channel1_frame3,...],
          [channel2_frame1, channel2_frame2, channel2_frame3,...]
          ...
          [channeln_frame1, channeln_frame2, channeln_frame3,...]]
```

So while it is possible to use np.zeros to create the fitting matrix form and then use a python loop to basically say:

```
matrix = np.zeros(#channels, len(data)/#channels)
for index in range(#channels):
     matrix[i] = data[i::#channels]
```

Can't I somehow do that with numpy alone? The performance gain might not be so high, especially because the amount of channels will be very low in most cases, but it kind of pisses me off that I've not been able to find a more "elegant" solution to this.

Thanks in advance if you have an idea,
have a nice weekend!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `numpy.reshape`:

```
data = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
matrix = np.reshape(2, 5)  # Assume 2 channels and 5 frames
print(matrix)
```

This code outputs

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10]])
```

In your case you would use `reshape(len(data)/#channels, #channels)` on your data.